# gnuplot multiple axes (x1y1, x1y2) to plot data from a single file

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to use multiple axes (2 axes x1y1, x1y2) to plot data from a single file. I am having trouble in get the right figure. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

I am parametrising my gnu plots.

```
gnuplot -e "datafile='output'; 
        mytitle = 'Latency Vs Packet number (Arrival Rate = 0.3125 pkts/sec, Schedule Rate = 2 pkts/sec) [ES]';
        outputname='latvspno_1024.jpg';
        x_label='Packet number';
        y_label='Packet Latency (Last bit entering to exiting)';
        y2_label='Queue Size (in bytes)';
        parameter1='Packet Latency';            
        parameter2='Queue Size' 
        " scriptv2.plt
```

This is my scriptv2.plt script that I use for plotting.

```
set   autoscale                        # scale axes automatically
unset log                              # remove any log-scaling
unset label                            # remove any previous labels
set xtic auto                          # set xtics automatically
set ytic nomirror                          # set ytics automatically
set y2tic                              # set ytics automatically
set nokey
set grid
#set term postscript eps#output terminal and file
#set output "qsim.ps"

#set terminal png
#set terminal jpeg medium size 640,480
set terminal jpeg large size 800,600
set output outputname

#set title "Plot of Queue length Vs time (based on config)"
set title mytitle
set xlabel x_label
set ylabel y_label
set y2label y2_label
set key left top


plot datafile axes x1y1 using 1:5 title parameter1 with linespoints pt 7 ps 2,\
      datafile axes x1y2 using 1:6 title parameter2 with linespoints pt 7 ps 2
```

The following is the contents of my datafile (called output)

```
0   128 0.4 1.4 1   0   256
1   128 0.8 2.4 1.6 128 512
2   128 1.2 3.4 2.2 256 640
3   128 1.6 4.4 2.8 256 896
4   128 2   5.4 3.4 384 1024
5   128 2.4 6.4 4   512 1152
6   128 2.8 7.4 4.6 512 1408
7   128 3.2 8.4 5.2 640 1536
8   128 3.6 9.4 5.8 640 1792
9   128 4   10.4    6.4 768 1792
10  128 4.4 11.4    7   896 1792
```

Comment: Please describe why this isn't the correct figure.  What do you get?  And what do you expect to get?

Comment: Thanks. I had some issues with the y axis ranges. But I think i have fixed it.

Comment: If you have solved this, you should accept your own answer so that the question is marked as solved.  If it was just a typo, it would be better to delete the question.

Comment: actually, SO allows us to accept our own answers only after 2 days from the day of posting.

Answer (score 1):

I just misplaced the axes position.

```
plot datafile  using 1:5 axes x1y1 title parameter1 with linespoints pt 7 ps 2,\
  datafile  using 1:6 axes x1y2title parameter2 with linespoints pt 7 ps 2
```